# type conversion not working javascript

Tags: javascript

I created a rather large function that takes in an argument, and based on the number's size, properly formats it. It works as expected for any values with the `typeof` number, however there are a few instances where I need to convert a string to a numeric value. I am trying to do that by using `parseInt` if its type is not `number`. When I `console.log` after the first if-statement, it says its `typeof` is now number. However when any string is passed through, say, "10000", it just shows up as 10000, and not the expected output of 10,000 with the proper formatting. Below is my code...are there any glaring ways that I might be going about it wrong?

```
function formatNumber(number) {
    if (typeof number !== 'number') {
        number = parseInt(number);
        return number;
    }

    let decimals = 2;
    const isNegative = number < 0;
    const rounded = (number >= 1e+6) ? Math.round(number) : number;

    const isInteger = () => parseInt(number, 10) === parseFloat(number);

    const abs = Math.abs(rounded);
    if (abs < 1e+6) {
        decimals = isInteger(abs) ? 0 : decimals;
    }

    const formatter = val => {
        const string = Math.abs(val).toString();
        let formatted = '';

        for (let i = string.length - 1, d = 1; i >= 0; i--, d++) {
            formatted = string[i] + formatted;
            if (i > 0 && d % 3 === 0) {
                formatted = `,${formatted}`;
            }
        }
        return formatted;
    };

    const formatLargeNumbers = (value, decimalPlaces) => {
        let adjustedValue;
        if (value >= 1e+12) {
            adjustedValue = parseFloat((value / 1e+12).toFixed(decimals));
            return `<span title=${formatter(value)}>${adjustedValue}T</span>`;
        }
        if (value >= 1e+9) {
            adjustedValue = parseFloat((value / 1e+9).toFixed(decimals));
            return `<span title=${formatter(value)}>${adjustedValue}B</span>`;
        }
        if (value >= 1e+6) {
            adjustedValue = parseFloat((value / 1e+6).toFixed(decimals));
            return `<span title=${formatter(value)}>${adjustedValue}M</span>`;
        }
        if (value >= 1e+3 && value < 1e+6) {
            return value.toLocaleString('en-EN', {
                minimumFractionDigits: decimalPlaces,
                maximumFractionDigits: decimalPlaces,
            });
        }
        return value.toFixed(decimals);
    };

    if (isNegative) {
        let negativeNumber = Math.abs(rounded);
        if (negativeNumber >= 1e+3) {
            negativeNumber = formatLargeNumbers(negativeNumber);
        }
        return `<span class="negative-value">(${negativeNumber})</span>`;
    }

    return formatLargeNumbers(rounded, decimals);
}
```

Comment: Which function and which `if` statement are you talking about specifically? You have a few number formatting functions here. It would help us help you if you are more specific.

Comment: You're returning immediately after doing the parse int. If you want the rest of the function to operate on that number, remove `return number;` on the third line of the function.

Comment: @NicholasTower total 'duhhhhhhhhhhhh!' moment now that you pointed that out. Appreciate the help!